# Pandas delete and shift cells in a column basis multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, shift, del

I have a situation where I would want to delete and shift cells in a pandas data frame basis some conditions. My data frame looks like this :

```
Value_1      ID_1      Value_2      ID_2         Value_3      ID_3
   A           1            D         1               G          1
   B           1            E         2               H          1
   C           1            F         2               I          3
   C           1            F         2               H          1
```

Now I want to compare the following conditions:

```
ID_2 and ID_3 should always be less than or equal to ID_1. If anyone of them is greater than ID_1 then that cell should be deleted and shifted with the next column cell
```

The output should look like the following :

```
    Value_1      ID_1      Value_2      ID_2         Value_3      ID_3
       A           1            D         1               G          1
       B           1            H         1           blank        nan
       C           1       blank        nan           blank        nan
       C           1            H         1           blank        nan
```

Comment: an empty string not a blank apologies..

Comment: In the original data, the columns are not like that.. like there is no number after the _ . you can treat the column names as A, B , C , D for simplicity

Comment: yes there are only 6 columns and selection can be made using names. the comparison would be made between the three columns, if the values in col ID_2 and ID_3 is less than or equal to ID_1 then it stays as it is otherwise shift as I have shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create mask by condition, here for greater values like `ID_1` by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html)::

```
cols1 = ['Value_2','Value_3']
cols2 = ['ID_2','ID_3']

m = df[cols2].gt(df['ID_1'], axis=0)
print (m)
    ID_2   ID_3
0  False  False
1   True  False
2   True   True
3   True  False
```

Then replace missing values if match mask by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df[cols2] = df[cols2].mask(m) 
df[cols1] = df[cols1].mask(m.to_numpy())
```

And last use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with set new columns by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df1 = df[cols2].shift(-1, axis=1)
df['ID_2'] =  df['ID_2'].mask(m['ID_2'], df1['ID_2'])
df['ID_3'] =  df['ID_3'].mask(m['ID_2'])

df2 = df[cols1].shift(-1, axis=1)
df['Value_2'] =  df['Value_2'].mask(m['ID_2'], df2['Value_2'])
df['Value_3'] =  df['Value_3'].mask(m['ID_2'])

print (df)
  Value_1  ID_1 Value_2  ID_2 Value_3  ID_3
0       A     1       D   1.0       G   1.0
1       B     1       H   1.0     NaN   NaN
2       C     1     NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
3       C     1       H   1.0     NaN   NaN
```

And last if necessary replace by empty strings:

```
df[cols1] = df[cols1].fillna('')
print (df)
  Value_1  ID_1 Value_2  ID_2 Value_3  ID_3
0       A     1       D   1.0       G   1.0
1       B     1       H   1.0           NaN
2       C     1           NaN           NaN
3       C     1       H   1.0           NaN
```