# Shuffle pandas columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, shuffle

I have the following data frame:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3  Type
0      1     2     3     1
1      4     5     6     1
2      7     8     9     2
```

and I would like to have a shuffled output like :

```
        Col3  Col1  Col2  Type
    0      3     1     2     1
    1      6     4     5     1
    2      9     7     8     2
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1, axis=1)
```

If need last column not changed position:

```
a = df.columns[:-1].to_numpy()
np.random.shuffle(a)
print (a)
['Col3' 'Col1' 'Col2']

df = df[np.append(a, ['Type'])]
print (df)
   Col2  Col3  Col1  Type
0     3     1     2     1
1     6     4     5     1
2     9     7     8     2
```

Comment: could you help me with one more question of mine that I posted yesterday?

Comment: I see, checking.

Comment: This is the question I am talking about : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591214/pandas-delete-and-shift-cells-in-a-column-basis-multiple-conditions